# Storing hashed password in Ms access?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2003

After hashing a password (SHA256) what data type must i use in MS access to save the hashed password, i am using the code from "http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/186585/Password-Storage-How-to-do-it", he says to use a "varbinary" column, but that is in SQL Server, so how do i do it in access (preferably MS Access 2003). Could i just use a text data type or do i have to convert it before saving? I researched a bit but couldn't find a definitive answer

Comment: Can't you convert it to base64 and store as string? You could then use char(32) as your type.

Comment: A human readable hex string seems like the way to go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

In Access, use TEXT (that will limit the hashed password to 255 characters) or MEMO (65K plus characters)

I have several databases using both types to store hashed passwords